# Create a matrix of neighbours

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a sparse matrix and I need to create a new neighbor matrix of each index.

Below I leave a representation of the data in the `NxM` matrix. For each of the elements of the matrix I need to obtain the neighbors in a section of `KxK`. With this information, it would generate a `NMxKK` matrix that contains in each row the indices of the neighboring KKs of the element.

[image]

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845507/calculate-distance-between-neighbors-efficiently/50851205#50851205) a while ago but the difference is that now the data is structured, so I can do without KdTree.

This new matrix is ​​used to calculate the distance of non-zero neighbors, and with these distances associate a weight to each neighbor, to finally estimate the desired value as a [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting) of the neighbors.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I have data like the ones in the image (generated with the function `generate_data`) and I need to perform the following operation.

[image]

Given a filter / kernel / `NxN` matrix, with `N` being the kernel size defined by me, calculate for nonzero values the distances with respect to the central pixel. Take as an example the value `20` that is in the position `(1, 8)` of the image. Taking a matrix of `5x5`, the nonzero values of interest are `40` (in `(0, 6)`), `37` (in `(1, 6)`) and `25` (in `(3, 10)`), with distances `2.23606798`, `2` and `2.82842712` respectively (obtained making the Euclidean norm between the indices).

What I need to get in this step is the matrix `res`:

```
[[0.         2.23606798 2.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         1.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         2.82842712]]
```

I need to obtain the `1.` in the center of the matrix too to also take into account the value where I am standing (whose distance to itself is `0.`).

With these values, I get the mask with non-zero values and calculate the weights based on a Gaussian distribution:

```
import scipy.stats as st 
mask = 0 < res
gauss = st.norm.pdf(res) # or st.norm.pdf(mask * kernel(5))

[[0.        , 0.03274718, 0.05399097, 0.        , 0.        ],
 [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
 [0.        , 0.        , 0.39894228, 0.        , 0.        ],
 [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
 [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.00730688]])

total = gauss.sum() # 0.4929873057962355
```

Finally, with these weights, I calculate the weights and the final value of the pixel by interpolating the values.

```
val[1, 8] = 0.03274718 * 40 / total + 0.05399097 * 37 / total + 0.39894228 * 20 / total + 0.00730688 * 25 / total
```

The same thing I must do for each pixel (I guess I have to add a `kernel_size padding // 2` to be able to use the whole array).

Here is my script

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

from scipy import sparse


def generate_data(m, n, density):
    s = 64 * sparse.random(m, n, density=density).A
    return s.astype(np.int8)


def plot_matrix(matrix):
    for (j, i), label in np.ndenumerate(s):
        plt.text(i, j, label, ha='center', va='center')

    plt.imshow(matrix)
    plt.show()


def kernel(n):
    n = n if n % 2 != 0 else n + 1
    mid = n // 2

    m = np.ndarray((n, n, 2))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            m[i, j] = np.array([i, j])

    return np.linalg.norm(m - [mid, mid], axis=2)


s = generate_data(10, 14, 0.25)
plot_matrix(s)
```

---

Comment: Hello! When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you provide a minimal, verifiable, complete example ([MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)): just a starting point for the people here that want to help you. This way we can just copy/paste the code and go straight into solving the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you really are asking.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I usually add examples but I had not thought of it from that point of view. This time I didn't add an MVCE because the matrices are very large, but now I'll update my question with a minimum example

Comment: I already updated my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really simple, although maybe not very efficient. What I had to do was two convolutions:

- In the first, it was convolucionar the Gaussian kernel with the matrix

  conv_1 = convolve2d(m * mask_clean, k_gauss)
- In the second, the Gaussian kernel with the mask

  conv_2 = convolve2d(mask_clean, k_gauss)

In each position, `conv_1` would have the sum of each value weighed by the corresponding factor of the Gaussian kernel. `conv_2` would have in each position the sum of all nonzero values. The only thing left to do was divide them to get the final result

```
# m have the data
mask_clean = (0 < m) & (m_mean - 3*m_std < m) & (m < m_mean + 3*m_std)

# Custom function to create a gaussian kernel
k = gkern(kernlen=5, std=5//2)
k_gauss = st.norm.pdf(k)

conv_1 = convolve2d(m * mask_clean, k_gauss)
conv_2 = convolve2d(mask_clean, k_gauss)
final = conv_1 / conv_2
```